# The SQL storage cannot change the schema for an existing field (id in sms_phone_number_verification entity) with data

Tags: 8, entities

I am using the [SMS Framework](https://www.drupal.org/project/smsframework) module and after updating my site from Drupal core `8.8.8` to Drupal Core `8.9.3` and the [SMS Framework](https://www.drupal.org/project/smsframework) module from `8.x-1.3` to `8.x-2.0.0-alpha1`, I start seeing the below error in "Status Report" Section (`/admin/reports/status`).

[image: Status Report Error]

and because `drush entup` is now deprecated, I had to install the [Devel Entity Updates](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_entity_updates) module so `drush entup` can work again.

However, After running `drush entup`, I faced another error as shown below:

[image: drush entup error]

1. How can I solve this error `In SqlContentEntityStorageSchema.php line 1887: The SQL storage cannot change the schema for an existing field (id in sms_phone_number_verification entity) with data.` without having to delete all related data from fields as the site has more than 50 000 registered phone numbers ?
2. Is it safe to ignore the `Mismatched entity and/or field definitions` error from the `Status Report` page ?

Thank you,

Comment: Encountered this issue today. Did you ever fix it?